# How to compile a pfSense port for ARM?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, arm, pfsense

How do I compile a pfSense port for ARM?

Do I need to be running FreeBSD to do it?  How do I then transfer it to a USB drive, SD Card, or ISO so I can boot it?

I tried the usual compiling in Ubuntu after I cloned the repo that I found listed in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71519/350), but I get an error....

First off there's no `./configure` file, and when I run `make` despite that there is indeed a `Makefile` I get the following error:

```
Makefile:69: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Is the repository I cloned more like a subproject to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use FreeBSD's package (see [here](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Installing_FreeBSD_Packages)). FreeBSD has packages for ARM (check http://pkg.freebsd.org/) - since 11.0.

But if you really want build your packages from ports please read [Using the Ports Collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html). You can build ARM packages on your (non-ARM) machine using [qemu](http://www.freshports.org/emulators/qemu-user-static) (see a short description [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/52994/)).